# Flow Cytometry FCS file data segment, linear data seems skewed

Tags: c, bioinformatics

**final and last update (I promise)**

The core of the problem is traversing the data, as Jonathan Leffler kind of alluded.  The binary data is "arranged" in a matrix.  For example, if I have 3 events and 4 parameters of bitwidth 8, the binary data

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

would look like

```
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
```

I have two for loops i & j, and I need to calculate the offset using that.

I initially had

```
(i * PAR * 2) + (j * PnB/8)
```

Where PAR is the number of Parameters, PnB is the bitwidth, and i is from 0 to total events and j is from 0 to PAR.  This is incorrect, and not sure how I got this formula.

==

I am working on an in-house flow analysis software and am running into some issues.  The FCS sample data file I am using to test the software was generated with FACSCaliber on MacOS 9 CellQuest.  When I extract the data points for FSC-H and SSC-H I don't get the same results as I would on other flow software (namely FlowJo).  I understand that data generated on MacOS 9 CellQuest is stored in big endian order and believe that I am correctly transforming the data as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < params[j-1].PnB/8; ++i)
{
    lebyte[i] = (bytes[(params[j-1].PnB/8)-1-i] & 0xff) << i*8u;
    cx |= lebyte[i];
}
```

The code may not be elegant but it seems to do what I intend it to do with known data samples.

PnB is the bitwidth
PnR is the channel value range

The result I get when using real flow data looks correct in that the values are within the range specified by PnR, i.e. if PnR = 1024 the data stored in the 16bit space is between 0 - 1023.

However, when I plot the data I get a skewed dot plot where the scatters bend towards the FSC-H x axis.

Here is an excerpt from the FCS 3.1 Standard (Data File Standard for Flow Cytometry, International Society for Advancement of Cytometry; P. 13):

> $BYTEORD/n1,n2,n3,n4/ $BYTEORD/4,3,2,1/ [REQUIRED]
>
> This keyword specifies the endianness of the data, i.e., the byte order used to binary store numeric data values in the data set. This value of the keyword corresponds to the order from numerically least significant {1} to numerically most significant {4} in which four binary data bytes are written to compose a 32-bit word in the data acquisition computer. The numbers are separated by commas (ASCII 44). Only two distinct values are allowed:
>
> - $BYTEORD/1,2,3,4/ (little endian, i.e., least significant byte written first, e.g., x86 based personal computers)
> - $BYTEORD/4,3,2,1/ (big endian, i.e., least significant byte is written last, e.g., PowerPC including older Apple Macintosh computers prior to switch to Intel-based architecture)
>     One of these values shall be used to specify the endianness even if the size of data values exceeds 32 bits ($DATATYPE/D/)

I apologize in advance if I did not do a good job explaining and would be happy to further clarify any points as necessary.  Any help will be very much appreciated.

**Update**
Attached image to illustrate point.
Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYfZG.png)

[image: Skewed SCC-H x FSC-H]

**Update 2**

I made a simplified version of the endian converter and tested it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int PnB = 16; // bitwidth of data stored for a specific channel value
    // for example the data value for sample A is stored in 16 bits.
    char bytes[PnB/8];
    unsigned int lebyte[PnB/8];
    unsigned int cx = 0;

    unsigned int b0, b1;

    /*  |  [0] |  [1] |
    *  | 0xff | 0x03 |
    */
    bytes[1] = 0x03;
    bytes[0] = 0xff;

    // in big endian print out

    b0 = (bytes[0] & 0xff) << 8u;
    b1 = bytes[1] & 0xff;

    cx = b0 | b1;

    printf("%d\n", cx);

    cx = 0;

    // convert to little endian

    for (int i = 0; i < PnB/8; ++i)
    {
        lebyte[i] = (bytes[i] & 0xff) << i*8u;
        cx |= lebyte[i];
    }

    printf("%d\n", cx);
}
```

The results were correct:

> 65283
>
> 1023

So I made the corrections to the original source code (changes made in original post to conserve space).

Additionally I am doing memcpy to copy data over from a buffer.

```
memset(bytes, '\0', sizeof(char)*params[j-1].PnB/8);
memcpy(bytes, databuf+((i*data->PAR*2)+(j*params[j-1].PnB/8)), params[j-1].PnB/8);
```

But I still get a skewed data.  It may be something to do with how the data is transformed.  I just can't find any information online and I'm sure the makers of FlowJo would be unwilling to share the secret ;).  I'll keep looking and see what I find.

**Update 3**

sorry to make it longer but additional information:

```
typedef struct _fcs_parameter {
    double f1;          // logarithmic decade
    double f2;          // minimum value on log scale
    unsigned int PnB;   // bitwidth
    unsigned int PnR;   // range
    fcs_events *events; // event data
    char *sname;        // short name
    char *lname;        // filter name
} fcs_parameter;
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a little more code.  Your conversion function is not obvious.  The normal way to deal with data in big-endian order is to a single loop through the appropriate number of bytes, yielding a 32-bit or 16-bit value as required, worrying about signs and so on as necessary.  Can you give a hex dump of say 32 bytes of the data?  And show how PnB is set (and where PnR comes into play), etc.

Comment: So I made the corrections to the original source code (changes made in original post to conserve space).  The hex out put was (for one example) Byte[0] = 0x04 and Byte[1] = FFFFFF04, and for another case 0x00 and 0xCD respectively.  I'm wondering if I am reading in the data wrong.

Comment: I'll need to take a little time to look this over. It would be good to have a hex dump of the first 32 bytes or so of the data, along with an indication of which bytes are from 16-bit integers and which from 32-bit integers.  For example: `0x0000: 7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and
`0x0010: 02 00 3E 00 01 00 00 00 E4 03 40 00 00 00 00 00` are two lines of 16 bytes (from an ELF binary, as it happens).  I've not marked the boundaries there...maybe: `0x0000: [7F 45 4C 46] [02 01] [01 00] [00 00 00 00] [00 00 00 00]` as a semi-plausible f'rinstance.

Comment: Here is the first 7 sets of 2 bytes (14 bytes) from the file.  The bitwidth is 16, and format should be big endian (at least the header indicates that it is). `02 88 01 81 00 00 00 00 00 0 0 0 0 0 0 00 00`.  I marked the boundaries (based on the standard) like so `[02 88] [01 81] [00 00] [00 00] [00 00] [00 00] [00 00]`.  Correct me if I am wrong but if its big endian `02 88` would be `8802` right? Which is out of range for this file since the PnR = 1024.

Comment: If the data is big endian, then (hex) `02 88` is `0x0288`.  It would be `0x8802` if the data was little endian.  Reading big endian is a lot easier than reading little endian.  The square bracket notation was an invention on the fly, not a standard. It just allowed for unambiguous grouping if there was a mixture of 16-bit and 32-bit values.  With uniform sizes (all 16-bit), there isn't as much need for the marking.

Comment: Thanks! I got big endian v. little endian confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the formula I was using to calculate the offset.

I should have used the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data->TOT; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data->PAR; ++j)
        {

        // code removed for brevity

        memset(bytes, '\0', sizeof(char)*params[j].PnB/8);
        memcpy(bytes, databuf+((i*data->PAR*params[j].PnB/8)+(j*params[j].PnB/8)), params[j].PnB/8);

        // more code here
        }
}
```

Thanks for all your help! I wouldn't not have realized that the problem was the way I was calculating the offset if you had not mentioned the PnB problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good hard look at the `memset()` and `memcpy()` lines you show.  Since you've not shown how `i` is set, nor what's in your `params` array of structures, it's a bit hard to interpret.  However, if you have any varying sizes in the `PnB` member, then I think your `memcpy()` offset calculation is bogus.

Here's some code and the output from it; you'll have to adapt it a bit to your scenario. The last section tries to emulate your `memset/memcpy` code, given that there's no explanation of a number of the variables you show.  It includes an alternative interpretation that seems to make more sense.

You could make some of the functions into `static inline`, assuming you have C99.  There are other bits of code that also assume C99.  It's not hard to fix it to C89, but I'm not going to do that for you.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static uint16_t convert_uint16be(uint8_t const *bytes)
{
    uint16_t r = (bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1];
    return r;
}

static uint32_t convert_uint32be(uint8_t const *bytes)
{
    uint32_t r = (((((bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1]) << 8) | bytes[2]) << 8) | bytes[3];
    return r;
}

static void print16(uint8_t const *bytes)
{
  uint16_t r1 = convert_uint16be(bytes);
  int16_t  r2 = convert_uint16be(bytes);
  printf("0x%.2X 0x%.2X = 0x%.4" PRIX16 " = %6" PRId16 "\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], r1, r2);
}

static void print32(uint8_t const *bytes)
{
  uint32_t r1 = convert_uint32be(bytes);
  int32_t  r2 = convert_uint32be(bytes);
  printf("0x%.2X 0x%.2X 0x%.2X 0x%.2X = 0x%.8" PRIX32 " = %11" PRId32 "\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], r1, r2);
}

int main(void)
{
    int PnB = 16; // bitwidth of data stored for a specific channel value
    // for example the data value for sample A is stored in 16 bits.
    char bytes[PnB/8];
    unsigned int lebyte[PnB/8];
    unsigned int cx = 0;
    unsigned int b0, b1;

    /*  |  [0] |  [1] |
     *  | 0xff | 0x03 |
     */
    bytes[0] = 0xff;
    bytes[1] = 0x03;

    // in big endian print out
    b0 = (bytes[0] & 0xff) << 8u;
    b1 = bytes[1] & 0xff;
    cx = b0 | b1;

    printf("%5d = 0x%.4X\n", cx, cx);

    // convert to little endian
    cx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < PnB/8; ++i)
    {
        lebyte[i] = (bytes[i] & 0xff) << i*8u;
        cx |= lebyte[i];
    }
    printf("%5d = 0x%.4X\n", cx, cx);

    print16((uint8_t *)bytes);

    uint8_t data[] =
    {
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFF,
      0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF,
      0x08, 0x08, 0x09, 0xC0,
      0x80, 0x80, 0x90, 0x0C,
      0xFF, 0xFF, 0xED, 0xBC,
    };
    int data_size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i += 2)
      print16(&data[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i += 4)
      print32(&data[i]);

    {
      struct { int PnB; } params[] = { { 16 }, { 16 }, { 32 }, { 16 }, { 16 }, };
      int num_params = sizeof(params) / sizeof(params[0]);
      uint8_t value[4];
      int i = 0;
      int num = num_params;
      int offset = 0;
      for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++)
      {
        memset(value, '\0', sizeof(char)*params[j-1].PnB/8);
        printf("i = %2d; j = %2d; offset = %2d; calc = %2d; size = %2d\n",
               i, j, offset, ((i*7*2)+(j*params[j-1].PnB/8)), params[j-1].PnB/8);
        /* The calculation works plausibly when all params[n].PnB are the same
         * size, but not otherwise
         */
        memcpy(value, data+((i*7*2)+(j*params[j-1].PnB/8)), params[j-1].PnB/8);
        if (params[j].PnB == 16)
          print16(value);
        else
          print32(value);
        memcpy(value, data+offset, params[j-1].PnB/8);
        if (params[j].PnB == 16)
          print16(value);
        else
          print32(value);
        offset += params[j-1].PnB/8;
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
65283 = 0xFF03
 1023 = 0x03FF
0xFF 0x03 = 0xFF03 =   -253
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0x03 0xFF = 0x03FF =   1023
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0xFF 0xFF = 0xFFFF =     -1
0x08 0x08 = 0x0808 =   2056
0x09 0xC0 = 0x09C0 =   2496
0x80 0x80 = 0x8080 = -32640
0x90 0x0C = 0x900C = -28660
0xFF 0xFF = 0xFFFF =     -1
0xED 0xBC = 0xEDBC =  -4676
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 = 0x00000000 =           0
0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF = 0x000003FF =        1023
0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF = 0x0000FFFF =       65535
0x08 0x08 0x09 0xC0 = 0x080809C0 =   134744512
0x80 0x80 0x90 0x0C = 0x8080900C = -2139058164
0xFF 0xFF 0xED 0xBC = 0xFFFFEDBC =       -4676
i =  0; j =  1; offset =  0; calc =  2; size =  2
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
i =  0; j =  2; offset =  2; calc =  4; size =  2
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 = 0x00000000 =           0
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 = 0x00000000 =           0
i =  0; j =  3; offset =  4; calc = 12; size =  4
0x08 0x08 = 0x0808 =   2056
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
i =  0; j =  4; offset =  8; calc =  8; size =  2
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
0x00 0x00 = 0x0000 =      0
i =  0; j =  5; offset = 10; calc = 10; size =  2
0xFF 0xFF 0x03 0xFF = 0xFFFF03FF =      -64513
0xFF 0xFF 0x03 0xFF = 0xFFFF03FF =      -64513
```

Comment: Thank you I will look into this and get back to you.  In my example, PnB is all the same (16) but it's good to know since the standard does mention that PnB can vary between channels.

Comment: I also realized after looking through your example that `(i*7*2)+(j*params[j-1].PnB/8)` should be `(i*data->PAR*2)+(j*params[j-1].PnB/8)` where `data->PAR` contains the number of parameters in the flow file.  The example file I was using is 7 so I had a static number.  The flow data is a matrix of number (assuming list storage) and is Events by Parameters.  The example file I used is 40,000 events by 7 params.

Comment: I'm definitely getting something funky.  Although between negative and positive samples I see a distinct population it may just be coincidental.  But the channel values I get from my program do not match with the channel values I've calculated manually by opening the FCS file in a bin viewer, suggesting my offset calculation must be incorrect like you alluded to.

Comment: If you want to send me email with a (compressed) tar file with the data file and your code, see my profile.  I won't be able to look until this evening (US/Pacific) at the earliest (so I suggest you work on it yourself, but contact me later if you still have issues).